# How to check whether different forms of Windows user account relate to the same user?

Tags: c#, domain-name

Windows account name can have various forms in different contexts - I am interested in bringing account name to some canonical form if possible, or in checking whether two account names apply to the same account in a context of a given machine. For example:

```
.\Hobson
HobMachine\Hobson
localhost\Hobson
```

or

```
HobDomain\Hobson
HOBSON@HOBDOMAIN
```

Above two sets of names name the same user each (when used in appropriate context, e.g. first one is checked on machine called HobMachine). How can I check programmatically (preferably C#), whether two account names apply to the same account in a context of given machine?

Comment: This is the problem that a domain controller solves.  One domain, one user, an account usable on multiple machines that are joined to the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but it seems like you'd have to decide that just by the name. I'm not aware of anything that links domain accounts to local accounts since they *are* different accounts.